# What is the best way to "adorn objects with functionality"?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, aop, adorner

I made the example below which enables a **factory** to pack objects with functionality, but the **problem** is that the functionality is **divorced from the object**.

My ultimate goal is attach functionality such as **log**, and **save** and **display** which operates on the specific properties that each different object has.

**How would I keep the exterior adorning aspect of this example but enable functionality such as "save" which saves the object's data to a database or "log" which logs its activity?**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace FuncAdorn3923
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Customer customer = new Customer();
            ObjectFactory.Instance.AdornFunctionality(customer, "add");
            Console.WriteLine(customer.CallAlgorithm("add", 64, 36));

            Employee employee = new Employee();
            ObjectFactory.Instance.AdornFunctionality(employee, "add");
            ObjectFactory.Instance.AdornFunctionality(employee, "subtract");
            Console.WriteLine(employee.CallAlgorithm("add", 5, 15));
            Console.WriteLine(employee.CallAlgorithm("subtract", 66, 16));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class ObjectFactory
    {
        private static ObjectFactory singleton;

        public void AdornFunctionality(AdornedObject ao, string idCode)
        {
            Func<int, int, int> add = (i, j) => i + j;
            Func<int, int, int> subtract = (i, j) => i - j;

            switch (idCode)
            {
                case "add":
                    ao.LoadAlgorithm(idCode, add);
                    break;
                case "subtract":
                    ao.LoadAlgorithm(idCode, subtract);
                    break;
            }
        }

        public static ObjectFactory Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (singleton == null)
                    singleton = new ObjectFactory();
                return singleton;
            }
        }

    }

    public abstract class AdornedObject
    {
        private Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, int>> algorithms = 
            new Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, int>>();

        public void LoadAlgorithm(string idCode, Func<int,int,int> func)
        {
            algorithms.Add(idCode, func);
        }

        public int CallAlgorithm(string idCode, int i1, int i2)
        {
            Func<int,int,int> func = algorithms[idCode];
            return func.Invoke(i1, i2);
        }
    }

    public class Customer : AdornedObject
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfProductsBought { get; set; }
    }

    public class Employee : AdornedObject
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Am I missing something or would extension methods solve this a little more elegantly?

Comment: On a side note, I believe the JIT instantiation of the singleton is not thread-safe.  The Right Way is to instantiate it as part of the field declaration; this is guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally recommend a better design pattern, like the visitor pattern, but for what its worth you can make your code work by throwing away type safety. Use `Delegate` rather than its derived classes `Func` and `Action`:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Customer customer = new Customer();
        ObjectFactory.Instance.AdornFunctionality(customer, "add");
        Console.WriteLine(customer.CallAlgorithm("add", 64, 36));

        Employee employee = new Employee();
        ObjectFactory.Instance.AdornFunctionality(employee, "add");
        ObjectFactory.Instance.AdornFunctionality(employee, "subtract");
        ObjectFactory.Instance.AdornFunctionality(employee, "save");
        Console.WriteLine(employee.CallAlgorithm("add", 5, 15));
        Console.WriteLine(employee.CallAlgorithm("subtract", 66, 16));
        Console.WriteLine(employee.CallAlgorithm("save"));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class ObjectFactory
{
    private static ObjectFactory singleton;

    public void AdornFunctionality(AdornedObject ao, string idCode)
    {
        Func<int, int, int> add = (i, j) => i + j;
        Func<int, int, int> subtract = (i, j) => i - j;
        Action save = () => Console.WriteLine("{0} has been saved", ao.ToString());

        switch (idCode)
        {
            case "add":
                ao.LoadAlgorithm(idCode, add);
                break;
            case "subtract":
                ao.LoadAlgorithm(idCode, subtract);
                break;
            case "save":
                ao.LoadAlgorithm(idCode, save);
                break;
        }
    }

    public static ObjectFactory Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (singleton == null)
                singleton = new ObjectFactory();
            return singleton;
        }
    }

}

public abstract class AdornedObject
{
    private Dictionary<string, Delegate> algorithms = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();

    public void LoadAlgorithm(string idCode, Delegate func)
    {
        algorithms.Add(idCode, func);
    }

    public object CallAlgorithm(string idCode, params object[] args)
    {
        Delegate func = algorithms[idCode];
        return func.DynamicInvoke(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why visitor instead of decorator?

Comment: Decorator is plausible, for sure, but decorators are supposed to implement the interface of the classes they decorate, so it can be a lot more work. (Additionally, given Edward's example, it looks like decorators would provide a different abstraction than the one he's looking for: encapsulating extended versions of existing interfaces rather than encapsulating algorithms that operate on those interfaces.)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a classic case for the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_Pattern).

The algorithms (visitors) will need to be tailored to the objects they adorn (or visit), or at least tailored to some interface that your adorned objects implement.

For example, your `Employee` object might have a method like the following:

```
public class Employee: IEmployee {
    public void Accept(IEmployeeAlgorithm algorithm) {
        algorithm.Visit(this);
    }
}
```

`IEmployeeAlgorithm` objects would have an interface similar to this (these could just as easily be `Action<Employee>` delegates, or use other signatures as needed):

```
public interface IEmployeeAlgorithm {
    void Visit(IEmployee employee);
}
```

Finally, if you want to give the algorithms keys and invoke them dynamically, you could do that in a fashion similar to what you've got now by storing them in an `IDictionary<string, IEmployeeAlgorithm>` member.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/) project.  They allow this kind of separation of concerns and enable some easy ways to accomplish this.  They allow you to externally define code which is added to classes/properties at run time.  I'm not sure about your specific requirements (or this particular example)  but you should check it out.